# Google App Engine with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc

I want to use GAE with Spring MVC

so, I found this following site.

[here](http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/google-app-engine-spring-3-mvc-rest-example/)

but This site's example seems to manually add jar files.

I think it is inefficient.

In eclipse, Is there another way like adding dependency on pom.xml in spring MVC project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you have created a maven project, then it is much easier to add dependencies using pom.xml.

You can edit directly, or use eclipse maven pom manager to add dependencies directly, or from a repository.

The link you gave does not create a maven project, but you can modify the instructions so it does.

You can create maven project instead of Web Application at the start, then add Spring dependencies and continue adding dependencies from there.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to git clone the [guestbook-spring project](https://github.com/gconcon/appengine-guestbook-spring-java) (it's adding Spring MVC to the GAE guestbook example) and continue from there.

We have builded our webapp app based on this, and it's great.

P.S. Also, it got tests for the controller included. It's good to have it as inspiration for testing you future app (as a developing practice).

Answer (score 0):

You could use gae archetype to create your project firstly, and then add spring components to pom.xml:

```
mvn archetype:generate -Dappengine-version=1.9.14 -Dapplication-id=your-app-id -Dfilter=com.google.appengine.archetypes
```

where -Dappengine-version is set to the most recent App Engine Java SDK version, and application-id is set to the Developer console application ID used for your app.

Answer (score 0):

I found simple way.

1.First, Create Spring MVC Project, and add dependency and plugin in pom.xml

1.1 add gae dependency

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.14</version>
 </dependency>
```

1.2 add gae plugin

```
  <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.14</version>
  </plugin>
```

2. In WEB-INF, create appengine-web.xml and logging.properties

then, you can run it on server

Comment: I tried this but when I want to deploy I get the message " test2 is not an App Engine project"

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Web Application project as it is shown, after that right click project -> Configure -> Convert to maven project.